# Taylor series representation of a function

Tags: calculus

[I'm given a function and asked to represent it as a Taylor series, but it seems that taking derivatives of this function gets more and more tedious.  Is there an alternative way to solve this problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPqLH.jpg)

Comment: In general, the answer is no, but for most common functions there are shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to let $u = x+2$ so that we want a power series in $u$. Note $x=u-2$ so that $1-2x = 1-2(u-2) = 5 - 2u$ so that we have the expression

$$\frac{5}{5 - 2u} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{2}{5}u} = \sum \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n u^n =  \sum \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n (x+2)^n$$

(remember the basic geometric series $\sum_{n\geq 0} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$)

Answer (score 0):

Also, calculating derivatives is easy:
$$f(x)=5(1-2x)^{-1}\\
f'(x)=5\cdot 2(1-2x)^{-2}\\
f''(x)=5\cdot 2\cdot 2(1-2x)^{-3}\\
f'''(x)=5\cdot 2^2\cdot 2\cdot 3(1-2x)^{-3}\\
...\\
f^{(n)}(x)=5\cdot 2^n\cdot n!(1-2x)^{-n-1}$$
For $x=-2$
$$f^{(n)}(-2)=5\cdot 2^n\cdot n!(5)^{-n-1}=\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n n!$$